# How to compile multiple objective C files into one library?

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to compile multiple objective C (.m) files into one .a library? The resulting code would be used in iPhone apps via XCode.

If yes, do you have any links to a tutorial, or can you paste a Makefile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a tutorial. Just start a new project, select iOS / Framework & Library / Cocoa Touch Static Library and start adding a files. That is it. Compiled lib will have all the files in place. Provide headers to consumers for all included files so they will know what's inside. It is pretty simple, let me know if you need an additional clarification.

Comment: Can I avoid having to provide headers for all the files? Can I provide a header just for the public looking .m?

Comment: It is actually the case. You provide a headers only for the objects that you want to be exposed to consumer.

Comment: How can I mark a file as role public? Can't find the option in Xcode4.

Comment: Found this: http://blog.carbonfive.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/making_headers_public.png and got it working.

Comment: But can I change the header path? Right now on my end the resulting header path is usr/local.